# Waking Device When Destination Reached

Tags: android, location, alarm

The program below is used for vibrating the phone when some destination is reached.This works perfectly when the screen is on but doesnt when the device is idle(SCREEN OFF) any suggestion so that it works while screen is off is very much appreciated.I am a novice in Android Development sorry if the question is stupid.`

```js
package com.sset.jibin.wakemethere;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class LocationActivity extends Activity implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationActivity";
    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 10;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 5;
    Button btnFusedLocation;
    TextView tvLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation;
    String mLastUpdateTime;

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate ...............................");
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);
        tvLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLocation);

        btnFusedLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
        btnFusedLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                updateUI();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Firing onLocationChanged..............................................");
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Log.d(TAG, "UI update initiated .............");
        if (null != mCurrentLocation) {
            double l = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
            double le = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();
            String lat = String.valueOf(l);
            String lng = String.valueOf(le);
            tvLocation.setText("At Time: " + mLastUpdateTime + "\n" +
                    "Latitude: " + lat + "\n" +
                    "Longitude: " + lng + "\n" +
                    "Accuracy: " + mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy() + "\n" +
                    "Provider: " + mCurrentLocation.getProvider());
                     MapsActivity MA = new MapsActivity();



            Location loc1 = new Location("");
            loc1.setLatitude(l);
            loc1.setLongitude(le);
            Log.d("=====>", "t5");
            SharedPreferences preff = getSharedPreferences("ll", 0);
             String lal = preff.getString("la", null);
             String lnl = preff.getString("ln", null);
            Log.d("=====>", "t5.1");
            Log.d("=====>", lal);
            Log.d("=====>", lnl);


            double la = Double.parseDouble(lal);
            double ln = Double.parseDouble(lnl);
            Location loc2 = new Location("");
            loc2.setLatitude(la);
            loc2.setLongitude(ln);
            Log.d("=====>", "t6");
            float distanceInMeters = loc1.distanceTo(loc2);

            Log.d("=====>", "t7");

            if (distanceInMeters < 20) {
                Log.d("=====>", "FOUND");



                 



                Vibrator v = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                // Vibrate for 500 milliseconds
                v.vibrate(500);

            }







        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "location is null ...............");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update resumed .....................");
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your location logic to a service. so it will run even if the application is leave by the user or screen is off.